# Is there a good upper bound for $(x-1)^n-x^n$ for $x\ge 1$ and $n=2,3,4,...$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

For an positive integer $n\ge 2$, is there a good upper bound for $(x-1)^n-x^n$ for $x> 1$? 
Revised question: Is it less than $-\log(x-1)$ for all $x>1$?

By Binomial theorem, $(x-1)^n-x^n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}(-1)^k$. Or by Mean Value Theorem, it is equal to $-n\xi^{n-1}$ for some $\xi\in(x-1,x)$. I wonder if there are good estimate of this function?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but isn't the maximum for that function with a positive integer $n\ge 2$ always $-1$ with $x=1$ ?

Comment: @JimB That upper bound is not good for large $x$.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?
In a way you've just made your expression more complicated. Calculating $(x-1)^n-x^n$ is a lot simpler than the sum.

Comment: I wonder if it less than $-\log(x-1)$?

Comment: @kccu.  Then I'm certainly misinterpreting the problem.  I was interpreting it as fixing $n$ and then finding the value of $x$ that maximizes the function.  How large is large?  `(x - 1)^n - x^n /. {n -> 5, x -> 100000000}` results in -499999990000000099999999500000001 using *Mathematica*.

Comment: @videlity I wonder if it less than $-\log(x-1)$?

Comment: @JimB Let me rephrase the question. Is it less than $-\log(x-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound $-n\zeta^{n-1} \le -n(x-1)^{n-1}$ is certainly less that $-\log(x-1)$ for $x \ge 2.

You can get better upper bounds by using Taylor approximations of $f(t) = t^n$ about $t = x$ and Lagrange's remainder term.  For example:
$$
(x-1)^n-x^n = -nx^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} n(n-1)\zeta^{n-2} \le 
-nx^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} n(n-1)x^{n-2} \, .
$$
and
$$
(x-1)^n-x^n = -nx^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} n(n-1)x^{n-2} - \binom{n}{3} \zeta^{n-3} \le 
-nx^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} n(n-1)x^{n-2} - \binom{n}{3}(x-1)^3\, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Made a mistake and the question changed.

Claim: $(x-1)^n-x^n < -\log(x-1)$ for $x>1$.

This is equivalent to showing that

$$  (x+1)^n-x^n > \log x, \qquad x>0 $$
Now
\begin{align}(x+1)^n-x^n &= nx^{n-1} + {n\choose 2} x^{n-2} + .... 
\\&>nx^{n-1}
\\&> x \qquad {\because n\geq 2 }
\\&>\log x.
\end{align}

As mentioned in the other answer, this bound is quite poor.

Comment: That cannot be correct. Compare the polynomial degrees of the two sides.

Comment: I just revised the question. I wonder if it is less than $-\log(x-1)$ for all $x>1$? It is definitely true for $x$ large enough by your estimate. But what about small $x$?

Comment: It is true. I will add a proof in an answer.

Comment: @HansEngler you are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: @Connor updated the answer.